# D3 Plot array of circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've tried the circle plot example as the following:

```
  var x=20, y=20, r=50;
  var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 800)
  .attr("height", 600);    

  sampleSVG.append("circle")
  .style("stroke", "gray")
  .style("fill", "white")
  .attr("r",  r)
  .attr("cx", x)
  .attr("cy", y);
```

But  I want to figure out how to plot without a loop a sequence of circles from an array like:

```
  data = [
          [10,20,30],
          [20,30,15],
          [30,10,25]
         ];
```

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks a lot this example is so helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this example could help?

```
var data = [
    [10,20,30],
    [20,30,15],
    [30,10,25]
];

var height = 300,
    width = 500;

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('width', width)
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(30, 30)');

// Bind each nested array to a group element.
// This will create 3 group elements, each of which will hold 3 circles.
var circleRow = svg.selectAll('.row')
    .data(data)
  .enter().append('g')
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        return 'translate(30,' + i * 60 + ')';
    });

// For each group element 3 circle elements will be appended.
// This is done by binding each element in a nested array to a
// circle element.
circleRow.selectAll('.circle')
    .data(function(d, i) { return data[i]; })
  .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('r', function(d) { return d; })
    .attr('cx', function(d, i) { return i * 60; })
    .attr('cy', 0);
```

[Live Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VVdr5/11/)

Comment: This is great example, but can you edit it to make the first data row be binded as cx, the second cy and the third column as r ?

Comment: I've got it, the problem for me was assigning data with `.data(dataset)` and how to represent this data on `cx` and `cy`. and I figured out that it works like with a function that iterats on data like `forEach`.

Comment: Exactly, along with `enter().append()` it's like saying `forEach` item in this `Array` create a circle and bind it to that item.