# d3.js translate header text above or below a circle based on array index

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array buyers that consisting of two arrays `var buyers =[arrayOne, arrayTwo]` which I use to create a set of circles. I would like to translate the text labels for each group of circles based on what array it is from.  Ideally it would look like this (sorry not enough rep to attach an image):
  text   text   [arrayOne - text above circles] 
 
   (c)   (c)
- - - - - - -   x-Axis
   (c)   (c)
   text text   [arrayTwo - text below circles]

I'm using the following code to generate circles

```
  // svg container
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var buyerGroup = svg.selectAll('g')
        .data(buyers)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
            return "translate(0," + i*(height/4) + ")";
        });

    var buyerCircles = buyerGroup.selectAll(".circle")
        .data(function(d,i){
            return buyers[i];
        })
        .enter();
```

It's very similar to the fiddle from the accepted answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22768467/4765367

Because I've bound the data to buyerCircles, I'm not sure how to determine\query which array I'm "in" to apply a new translation when appending text.  This is the code I'm using to apply text "headers" to my circles.  This will only put text labels above a circle.

```
buyerCircles.append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
               return(d.label);
        })
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-weight","bold")
        .style("font-size", 18;
        })
        .attr("transform", function(d,i){
          return ("translate(" + xDomain(d.value) + "," + (height / 4 - 60) + ")" );
        });
```

Any suggestions would be most helpful.

Comment: Sorry, not clear... so `buyers` is `[arrayOne, arrayTwo]`, correct?

Comment: That's correct, thanks for the question, I will edit my post for clarity

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to do this by introducing a variable outside of the scope of buyerCircles called labelNumber.

```
var labelNumber=0;
```

Then when I append my text I increment labelNumber by 1: `labelNumber++;`
and then in my transform function I include an if statement referencing the value of labelNumber:

```
attr("transform", function(d){
            labelNumber++;
             if (labelNumber>3)
                 return ("translate(" + xDomain(d.value) + "," + (height / 4 + 73) + ")" );
             else
                return ("translate(" + xDomain(d.value) + "," + (height / 4 - 45) + ")" );
         });
```

This may not be the most elegant way to do this, but it works.  Definitely open to other other suggestions.